Automatically Vary LFO Speed Resistance Value
I have a basic tone generator circuit with LFO speed controlled by a 50K pot (variable resistor). I would like this resistance to fall (or rise, but I guess fall might be easier) after the circuit has been triggered (powered on and off). So the resistance falls by say 5k Ohm over 1 second after the circuit power has been cut. Creating a ramp or slope of resistance that slows or speeds up the LFO and creates interesting audio.
Circuit is based around a 4093 IC.
I wondered what people thought would be the best (analog) way of achieving this?
I thought maybe a LDR with capicitor that drains slowly after the power goes?
Sorry I'm not too skilled in electronics but I hope I have explained the situation clearly enough!
TIA

Could you post the schematics? As the 4096 is a digital chip, it is hard to guess in which way the pot affects the circuit. After that, there might be various ways to apply the same effect that wiggling the pot.

@Justme sure, it's a modified version of the circuit in the added image. The 100k lin pot is the one I am referring to (25K or 50K in my case). Exactly, the effect of turning the pot but automatically would be ideal, cheers.
